# Getting SQLite database backup with dynamic file name

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I get the latest SQLite database (on the screenshot below, I want to get 11408102018000005) has been back up on SD Card if there is more than one `.db` file?

**Note:**

The file type is dynamic. so the last number on the image is incrementing.

This is the image:
[image]

and this is my code when restoring a SQLite database.

```
private void restoreDB() {
    try {
        File[] sd = getContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null);

        if (sd[1].canWrite()) {
            File backupDB = new File(sd[1] + "/" + curControlNo);    //<--- what to put here. This is just a test path and name
            File currentDB = new File(getContext().getDatabasePath(DBHelper.DB_NAME).getPath());

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            openHome();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the database is currently opened and being used, that's not a safe way to copy it, btw.

Comment: what you mean its not the safe way?

Comment: [Read this](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_backup_or_restore_while_a_transaction_is_active)

Comment: Oh, How can I avoid it? close first then back and open again?

Comment: There are a couple of ways listed in that link (And more information in the link to the backup api documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create file and pass DB name that you want to save like below:

```
File backupDB = new File(sd[1], DBHelper.DB_NAME);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: How can I get the latest one?. I already have a code that creates an backup file

Comment: I have a solution of it now, on my `backup()` method, I will just need to make a backup that named after on `DB_NAME` and when i will restore it. I will just get it. The idea came up with your answer. thanks mate!

Comment: @MikeGorospe I am happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **File**'s **`listFiles`** method to get an array of the files in the directory, sort the array so the latest is first in the list and then use the first element of the array. e.g.

```
File[] dirlist = sd.listFiles(); //<<<<<<<< gets the list of files
```